# Modal window aligning to bottom in Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have bootstrap modal window, I is displaying correctly on browser with top 50%

```
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 50%;
}
```

But on mobile screen the modal window not displaying correctly it is aligning at bottom. I have checked in firbug and found that the top 50% attribute changing to top auto

```
.modal.fade.in {
  top: auto;
}
```

Because the mobile screen window is small bootstrap responsive js changing this attribute.

As finding this I am thinking of writting css class as below in my own css which will override bootstrap css code

```
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 50% !important;
}
```

So modal window will always align at top with 50% top attribute

Let me know if this is OK or there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are other solutions, but as soon as you keep this property (the last one with !important) in one of YOUR css file, it won't cause any problem ;)